# I seem to be getting a positional parameter error with mailmessage in powershell at 144

Tags: powershell, email, automation, mailmessage

Below is the code to an internal tool I was put in charge of setting up. It basically references a spreadsheet based on a known value and uses some of that information for sorting purposes and uses other information to populate the automated email. I've had several versions of it working but it seems that for whatever reason it acts like one of the variables isn't populated or is no longer accepting a string as a valid data type. I'm rather new to stack exchange so if there is any formatting or anything I could do to clear up what seems to be the issue, I'll be happy to oblige.

```
echo off #hiding my stuff
$Setup = Test-Path "$env:APPDATA\ExcelLocation.txt"
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
$OpenFileDialog.filter = "XLSX (*.xlsx)| *.xlsx"
$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$OpenFileDialog.filename
}

if($Setup -eq $False){
Write-Host "Please participate in 1st time setup!"
$FilePath = Get-FileName "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\"
$FilePath | Out-File "$env:APPDATA\ExcelLocation.txt"
$Setup -eq $True
}

$FilePath = Get-Content -Path "$env:APPDATA\ExcelLocation.txt"
Write-Host $FilePath
$DealerCodeLookup = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please put in the Dealer code.'

#Specify the path of the excel file
#$FilePath = "C:\Users\LAB\Downloads\2017 02 Custom Cellular Hierarchy.xlsx"

#Specify the Sheet name
$SheetName = "Sheet1"

# Create an Object Excel.Application using Com interface
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
# Disable the 'visible' property so the document won't open in excel
$objExcel.Visible = $false

# Open the Excel file and save it in $WorkBook
$Workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath, 2, $True) 
# Load the WorkSheet 'BuildSpecs'
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item($SheetName)
#$WorkBook.sheet | Select-Object -Property Name

  $Row = 1
  $Column = 5
  $Found = $False
  while (($WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column).Value() -ne $Null) -and     ($Found -eq $False)) {
                                                                                    #^-- looping though the excel list, updating the row. Stop if Cell is Empty or     Value is Found
If (($WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column).Value()).ToUpper() -eq $DealerCodeLookup.ToUpper()) {
                                                                                #^-- Cell value equals $Arg
  $locale = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+1).Value() 

  $State =$WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+10).Value()

  $Adrs = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+7).Value(),$WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+9).Value(),
  $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+10).Value(),$WorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row, $Column+11).Value() 
  $Found = $True
}
    $Row += 1                                                                            #Continue to the next row
  }
  Write-Host $State
  $LastRow = $WorkSheet.UsedRange.rows.count + 1
  if($Row = $LastRow -and $Found -eq $False){
  Write-Host "What you put in is not a valid dealer code!"
  $objExcel.quit()
  exit
  }
$objExcel.quit()

#$DealerCode = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please put in the Dealer code.'                     #stores the dealer code
$DealerName = 'CUSTOM CELLULAR'                                                       #Default dealer name (we are custom cellular)
#$Locale = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please put in the Location name.'                       #This stores the human location name
#$Address = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please put in the Location Address.'                   #This stores their address and the thing we use to determine the email address      that is sent.
$SoftTokenAmount = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please put in the amount of tokens needed.' #This stores the amount of tokens needed
$Reason = Read-Host -Prompt 'Why do you have to order these tokens??'             #This stores the reason for our request



#$SoutheastArea = '* MO *','* KS *','* IL *','* WI *','* MN *','* IA *','*     IN *','* NE *' <--possible more efficient usage of the determining loop

#Below is the if statement that determes the     Region(SoutheastArea,CenteralArea,WesternArea)

    #This specific loop is for the SoutheastArea
if($State -like '*MO*' -or ($State -like '*KS*') -or ($State -like '*IL*') -    or ($State -like '*WI*') -or ($State -like '*MN*') -or ($State -like '*IA*')-or      ($State -like '*IN*') -or ($State -like '*NE*'))
    {
        $To = "shalasere1@gmail.com"
    }


    #This loop is for the CentralArea   
Elseif($State -like '*TN*' -or ($State -like '*GA*'))
    {
        $To = "shalasere2@gmail.com"
    }

    #This loop is for the WesternArea
Elseif($State -like '*CO*' -or ($State -like '*UT*'))
    {
        $To = "shalasere3@gmail.com"
    }

$From = "tokenrequest@ccinational.com" #Default from email, mine.
#$Cc = "YourBoss@YourDomain.com"  #Optional CC'd users to said email     (possibly yours.)
$Subject = "Token Request"        #The subject of the email

#Below is the default contents of the email including the variables entered   above.
$Body = "                         
New/Replacement Token Request:



Dealer Name: $DealerName


Dealer Code: $DealerCodeLookup


Location: $locale
(office name)


Address: $Adrs


Dealer Email:


Amount of Soft Tokens Needed: $SoftTokenAmount


Reason for Request: $Reason"

#This final chuck is the actual sending an email smtp information for gmail
$SMTPServer = "smtp.office.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "publicpass" -AsPlainText -Force 
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential     ("TokenRequest@whereiwork.com", $secpasswd)

Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject `
-Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -dno onSuccess, onFailure  -port     $SMTPPort -UseSsl `
-Credential  $mycreds 
#= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential     ("TokenRequest@whereiwork.com", $secpasswd)
#(new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("scott","","ccin****.com"))
#(Get-Credential) #<- this line prompts for the outlook  login of the     default email (mine.) User is jacob@r**** and password is 8888!
```

Send-MailMessage : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '='.
At G:\Token Request v2.0.ps1:144 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it was required to have a single ' around the from subject to be passed correctly.